# popover content view doesn't display while viewcontroller has a child VC present

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a container view controller that consists of a navigation view at top, and a content view for the remainder of the screen.  The navigation menu consists of several buttons, some of which present a popover with UITableView for secondary navigation.  This all worked until I assigned a child view controller and set it's view as subview of the content view.  Now, the popover appears, but has nothing inside it (no tableview, just black).

Why is this?
Here's the code I added for the child vc in container view:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  ContentWebViewController *initialVC = [[ContentWebViewController alloc] init];
  [self addChildViewController:initialVC];
  initialVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
  [self.containerView addSubview:initialVC.view];
  self.currentController = initial;
}
```

See the screenshot below.  I added a vc with a simple webview showing google (just as a placeholder for now).  The popover was working fine before I assigned the child VC.

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I somehow (don't ask me how) changed the class that my table view controller was inheriting from.  It should have been (obviously) UITableViewController, but was UITableViewController, so initWithStyle was not being called....

Comment: ...do you know what did you changed, when you say "UITableViewController, but was UITableViewController". I can't seem to find any difference between the 2. Kinda stuck due to a similar situation.

Comment: please correct the answer... "It should have been (obviously) UITableViewController, but was UITableViewController" ??!!??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help other in other cases - 
If you are using size classes (probably you are since you are developing this to iPad) - 
Design your popover view controller in Any-Any size and it should be OK - after that you can return to your wanted size.
(You can also uninstall the size classes of any object in that view controller instead of redesign the VC)